# Finding a CID reference for attachments in Exchange Contacts

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm crafting a powershell program using EWS that:

- Recover some data from a backup contact folder (telephone, url, notes field,...)
- Set back those values in default contact folder in the new contact

Everything does work except, of course, attachents that were added to notes fields, still i'm able to download them.

```
        foreach ($attch in $Item.Attachments)
        {
            $downloadDirectory = ".\attachments"
            $attch.Load()
            $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDirectory + “\” + $attch.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
            $fiFile.Write($attch.Content, 0, $attch.Content.Length)
            $fiFile.Close()
            write-host "Downloaded Attachment : " + (($downloadDirectory + “\” + $attch.Name.ToString())) 

        }
```

Or upload them. (it's static here for test purpose)

```
$att = $item.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("C:\Scripts\myscript\attachments\PowerShell_transcript.20140506143510.txt")
$att.ContentId = 'test'
$att.IsInline=$false
```

Ideally, i was looking for matching CID references and uplading back attachments using the same one.

```
    <div><font face="Calibri" size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;">
<img src="cid:0DF540471453B832E300400FF03B0900CFEC1201@1"> 
    <a href="cid:74D8EEA6180AD131B48DC59373FABBABD7E361BB@1">SomeDoc.docx</a>
    </span></font></div>
```

Of course, when the object retrieved from exchange, it doesn't have a contentid (I would have guess it should be CID value).

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FileAttachment</T>
      <T>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment</T>
      <T>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FileAttachment</ToString>
    <Props>
      <Nil N="FileName" />
      <BA N="Content"></BA>
      <B N="IsContactPhoto">false</B>
      <S N="Id">AAMkADdmMDBkOTk4LTNlYzMtNDk1MS05ZTdhLWJmOGE.....</S>
      <S N="Name">SomeDoc.docx</S>
      <S N="ContentType">application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</S>
      <Nil N="ContentId" /> <=== WHERE IS MY VALUE :'(
      <Nil N="ContentLocation" />
      <I32 N="Size">1764632</I32>
      <DT N="LastModifiedTime">2016-01-26T15:08:03+00:00</DT>
      <B N="IsInline">false</B>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Does someone know a way to retrieve that value ?

- Server/mailbox: Exchange 2013 SP1

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> > it doesn't have a contentid (I would have guess it should be CID value).

An Attachment would only have cid if it was on Inline Attachment in a Mime Message https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2111.txt in a contact it would never be valid (eg even the contact picture doesn't have a cid) as your dealing with Exchange Data Type.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen, it's probably some Microsoft way of doing things. There's should be this info somewhere otherwise opening those files wouldn't work.

Comment: To open an Attachment in EWS it uses the AttachmentId property and in MAPI  its the Attachment Number so I'm not quite sure what you mean by that ?. Contacts are rich datatypes in Exchange they aren't MIME messages if you actually request the MIMEContent on a Contact Exchange will return a VCard.

Comment: Ok. But how's outlook is able to match cid:74D8EEA6180AD131B48DC593 with that attachment if this value isn't stored somewhere?

Comment: Match in regards to what ? rendering the body of a Message ? My suggest would be that you look at few object with a Mapi editor like MFCMapi or Outlook Spy. If the cid has been set on a message that is where you will see it. The cid is meant to be way for you to reference an Attachment in the body of a message. You can set the contentid on an attachment with (but only at time of creation) but it won't be set by default if its not needed.